# Need a list of row-values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

#### What I have, and what I need

I have a pandas DataFrame `p` with cols `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` (col names stored in `pc`).

From that I would like to create a DataFrame `pn` of the same shape, but each cell as a **list of values** from selected rows.
The DataFrame `n` tells me which rows to select from `p` for each row in `pn`.

```
import pandas as pd

pc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
p  = pd.DataFrame([[11, 12, 13],
                   [21, 22, 23]],
                  columns=pc,
                  index=[1001,
                         1002])

n  = pd.DataFrame([[[1001]      ],
                   [[1001, 1002]]],
                  columns=['sel_row'],
                  index=[1001,
                         1002])
```

#### What I *could* (and *want to*) achieve

The farthest I could get... gives me a list of cols, rather than rows.
So, am I confusing the nested `for` loops ?

```
pn = pd.DataFrame([ [p.loc[ix, pc].values for ix in n.loc[indx].values[0]] 
                    for indx in n.index ])

print (pn)

# The actual output:
#               0             1
# 0  [11, 12, 13]          None
# 1  [11, 12, 13]  [21, 22, 23]

# The required output:
#           0         1         2
# 0  [11]      [12]      [13]
# 1  [11, 21]  [12, 22]  [13, 23]
```

#### Stray thoughts

Maybe I should also iterate something like `p.loc[ix, c] ... for c in pc`... but how can there be 3 loops ??

#### A further (optional) wish

Is this possible with `lambda` too ? My intuition is: that would be faster-- but not sure !

Thanks for going through the question or any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom function here.

```
pc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
p  = pd.DataFrame([[11, 12, 13],
                   [21, 22, 23]],
                  columns=pc,
                  index=[1001,
                         1002])

n  = pd.DataFrame([[[1001]      ],
                   [[1001, 1002]]],
                  columns=['sel_row'],
                  index=[1001,
                         1002])
def f(idx):
    return pd.Series(p.loc[idx, :].values.T.tolist())

n.sel_row.apply(f)

             0         1         2
1001      [11]      [12]      [13]
1002  [11, 21]  [12, 22]  [13, 23]
```

With `lambda` could rewrite above as:

```
n.sel_row.apply(lambda idx: pd.Series(p.loc[idx, :].values.T.tolist()))
```

Comment: I like this answer the most... as it looks really simple and understandable.  Only perplexed to see how `f` can be applied without its parameter `idx` !

Comment: With a little print statement I think I got it: `idx` is each element of `n.sel_row` !  I was actually more familiar to the syntax: `n.sel_row.apply(lambda idx: f(idx))`.  Thanks for this shortcut !! 

Answer (score 3):

You can explode the `n`, use that to slice `p` and groupby:

```
s = n['sel_row'].explode()
p.loc[s].groupby(s.index).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
             a         b         c
1001      [11]      [12]      [13]
1002  [11, 21]  [12, 22]  [13, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could do:

```
data = [[[*x] for x in zip(*p.loc[idxs].values)] for idxs in n['sel_row']]

result = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=p.columns, index=p.index)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
             a         b         c
1001      [11]      [12]      [13]
1002  [11, 21]  [12, 22]  [13, 23]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, those column names and index are something very useful !